# How to load the data from datapath from annotation file

Tags: python, dataframe, deep-learning, image-preprocessing, data-preprocessing

Hi i have a custom dataset for sign language. I want to load the dataset from directory but directory is also there for each image stored as value in the column name "Framespath" in the file annotation.csv and type of that column is dataframe.

The below link is the sample of my dataset.

[Annotation file that consists both the label and directory path of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh4Fn.png).

I want to know, how to load the image data using path value from "Framespath" column. Please give me the suggestions which will be helpful for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Done editing..! please help me out